# Google Sheets' conditional formatting on list from another sheet

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have data validation set up in my sheet so that `Sheet1` cells can accept one of the values from `Sheet2` list.

Since `Sheet2` has 2 columns, I would like to make conditional formatting so that if an item from column A is selected that I show one color, and if an item from column B is selected that I can show another one.

I have tried setting to format if

> Text contains `=JOIN(", ",INDIRECT("Sheet2!C2:C"))`

As well as

> Text contains `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!C2:C")`

But none of these work.

Can I do this somehow?

**EDIT**

Also tried to do

> Custom formula `=ArrayFormula(sum(countif(B2:I26, Studenti!B2:B)))>0`

Which does seem to do its work on its own, but inside format rule doesn't

Comment: It contains names from business, can't do it unfortunately. Can I provide more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**green color:**

```
=FILTER(A1,COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet2!C1:C"),A1))
```

**red color:**

```
=FILTER(A1,COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet2!D1:D"),A1))
```

[image: 0]