# Google Sheets - conditional formatting on two columns based on two columns in a different sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I've looked at similar questions and answers but haven't been able to get it to work for me, unfortunately. I just can't really wrap my head around the answers well.

I have two sheets in a file, let's just say sheet 1 and sheet 2. On sheet 1 I have two columns to which I want to apply conditional formatting. On sheet 2 I have two columns which the info is checked against.

The contents of the cells in column A and B on any given row must exactly match the contents of both cells in column A and B on sheet 2.

For example... if sheet 1 column A has "sheep" and column B has "grass", the cell becomes green if on sheet 2 column A also has "sheep" and column B has "grass". However, if sheet 1 column A is "sheep" and column B is "water", is does not become green even if "water" does appear in sheet 2 column B but with, say, "fish" in column A.

I hope that makes sense... I'm having trouble explaining it properly :(

I currently have a working version but with all the information manually added into the conditional formatting box. It does not pull any information from another sheet. It works but is a ton of work to edit.

I've tried pretty much all combinations of [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126042/can-conditional-formatting-reference-other-sheet/126045#126045), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908540/conditional-formatting-highlight-words-from-a-list-if-present-in-another-list/54910481#54910481) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288769/google-sheets-conditional-formatting-on-list-from-another-sheet) that I could think of, but I'm very new to all of this so I've probably done something wrong.

I could not get the code in conditional formatting to validate; the box always keeps its red outline.

Comment: Hi can you share your Google Sheet with us? Or can you paste the formulas you tried in conditional formatting which gave you the red outline?

Comment: I've tried too many things and deleted them in frustration, but here's the sheet: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vhwPH4wJ_aYbPnOVj4PJAy-LUNFJA_KgnywQHOUm5ig/edit?usp=sharing)

The relevant sheets: "Living Ability Formdex" columns R and S and "Config" (very empty right now to get the concept working first, it'll get filled out after)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `Living Ability Formdex` tab, select the range `R2:S` and apply the custom formula for CF

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("CONFIG!A:A"),$R2,INDIRECT("CONFIG!B:B"),$S2)
```